# How to map xpath of web element in its actual class?

Tags: selenium, xpath, ui-automation, browser-automation

I am creating a framework in selenium  from scratch where i am scripting below scenarios:

1.Login in to https://www.yahoomail.com
2.entering username
3.entering password
4.click on Sign-In
5.click on Compose button
6.Enter Email ID, Subject and Message body.

Below is the code script i have written for above scenario:

```
WebDriver oYahoo = new FirefoxDriver();
        oYahoo.get("http://www.yahoomail.com/");
        oYahoo.manage().window().maximize();
        oYahoo.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='login-username']")).sendKeys("abcdefasdf@yahoo.com");
        oYahoo.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='login-passwd']")).sendKeys("sfgas234@123");
        oYahoo.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='login-signin']")).click();
        oYahoo.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Compose']/button")).click();
        oYahoo.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='yui_3_16_0_1_1448364357109_2222']")).sendKeys("abcdefgh@gmail.com");
        oYahoo.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='subject-field']")).sendKeys("Hi This is my first automated mail");
        oYahoo.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='yui_3_16_0_1_1448364357109_1966']")).sendKeys("Hi This is my first automated mail");
        oYahoo.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='yui_3_16_0_1_1448364357109_2465']")).click();
        oYahoo.quit();
```

Scripts fine till it clicks on "Compose" button, Once i get Mail editor, Script does not enters email-ID,Subject, and Message body.

What other action i should perform to achieve the same so that script will enter these parameters and can send a mail to particular user.

Do we need to create some class which will maps the locators to "compose-Email" screen?

If yes, how we can map/assign x-path to particular web element of Compose-Email page.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: After clicking compose button, does the "compose-Email" page appears in a pop-up or a new window ?

Comment: what exactly problem? form doesn't open or forms opens but not enter information?

Comment: @AritroSen: I think its a "pop-up". do we handle popups and windows differently ?

Comment: @MahsumAkbas: "Compose-Email" form opens but does not enters information.

Comment: yes of course. But here your login ID says that its inactive.

Comment: Thanks @AritroSen: how we can handle that window, what things we have to do. and how i will map the components of that "Compose New Email" window? so that i can use them in my script.

Comment: Just provide me a with valid login and password. I will explain to you then.

Comment: @AritroSen
do we really need valid login and pass ?
Good if we can have dummy ID and password. i will update my script accordingly.

Comment: Yes anything will be fine. Just provide me an username and password with which i can login and click the "compose email" button.

Comment: @AritroSen: you can use ID as "mdm_user@yahoo.com" with pass: Test_123

Answer (score 0):

Well you should try by using the xpath and enter the required text. Something like this (it works for me)-

```
oYahoo.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='to-field']")).sendKeys("xxxx@xxx.com");
oYahoo.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='subject-field']")).sendKeys("My first automated email");
oYahoo.findElement(By.id("rtetext")).sendKeys("Hello....Hi....This is my first automated email");
```